# Is it plausible to uswe spring-data-jdbc in a scenario where the DB-schema differs from the domain-model

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I'm considering using spring-data-jdbc for a project.
But i don't have any control over the DB-schema.
My domain model can be populated by the existing tables, but they differ in many ways.

Examples:

- A specific aggregate in my model consists of nested Value-Objects. The corresponding table only features flat columns, so the nested Value-Objects would have to be mapped manually.
- One the other hand, there are aggregates that don't have many nested Value-Objects, but the corresponding tables are organized according to a star-schema, so the values are distributed over many tables (instead of a single one).

I guess this prevents me from using many of the Quality-Of-Life features (like Query-Derivation and  Mapping).

Do I actually get anything significant out of spring-data-jdbc in comparison to using a plain `JdbcTemplate` in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario you describe would make me tend towards plain `JdbcTemplate`.
But I would consider using the Aggregate approach Spring Data JDBC does:

- Load complete aggregates
- Reference between aggregates using ids, or something like an `AggregateReference`

And if you have an aggregate that actually can be mapped using Spring Data JDBC you can still do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took the middle road now: i created views on the DB that roughly correspond to my aggregates. Furthermore i created DTOs that enable me to use Query-Derivation. Then i only have to map those DTOs to the Aggregates in my model (i do that in encapsulating "Business"-Repositories around the CrudRepositories). They are roughly the same. My Aggregates just tend to be in a more nested structure because i use many ValueObjects instead of "native" types like Integer or String. This way i can use some of the QoL-Feature of spring-data-jdbc without compromising my domain model.